# How to set image to the button using Win32APi c++?

Tags: c++, image, winapi, button

I need to set image to the button. The main idea is to make image clickable, and when click on it some event happens.

```
case WM_CREATE:
        HANDLE hBmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), 
                                        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1), 
                                        IMAGE_BITMAP, 
                                        NULL, 
                                        NULL,
                                        LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
        HWND hButton = CreateWindow(L"button", L"Label",
            BS_BITMAP | WS_VISIBLE |WS_CHILD,
            10, 10,
            1366, 699,
            hWnd, (HMENU)MAP_BUTTON1,
            hInst, NULL);

        SendMessage(
            (HWND)hWnd,
            (UINT)BM_SETIMAGE,
            (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP,
            (LPARAM)hBmp);
        break;
```

After executing this I have something starnge like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOgAP.png)

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You need to explain what you expect, and what you have. *"Something starnge"* is not a useful error description. And you absolutely need to check for errors. 2 of the API calls above can fail, but your code doesn't check for that.

Comment: @IInspectable see picture that i attached. There you can see a border of big button, but there is no image on it. I cannot attach the picture itself, because I have less than 10 reputation.

Comment: Please do not edit the question in a way that invalidates already posted answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following problems:

- You don't do any error checking. Perhaps `LoadImage` fails. Perhaps `CreateWindow` fails.
- You get the type wrong for `hBmp`. It should be `HBITMAP`.
- When sending `BM_SETIMAGE`, you are passing the handle of the button's parent rather than the handle of the button.

Comment: Can you teach how to do it? I am here because I learn, but it is very sad when nowbody tells me how to solve the problem. I added ```if (!CreateWindow(L"button", L"Label",
   BS_BITMAP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
   10, 10,
   1366, 699,
   hWnd, (HMENU)MAP_BUTTON1,
   hInst, NULL))
  {
   MessageBox(hWnd, L"CreateWindow failed", L"Error", MB_OKCANCEL);
   return NULL;
  }```  and the same to `LoadImage` fucntion, but still nothing happens. And how to send `BM_SETIMAGE` directly to button?

Comment: I suggest that you address all three problems. It seems clear that the button is created so the advice for error checking on CreateWindow is more general advice. Does LoadImage succeed? Why are you sending `BM_SETIMAGE` to the wrong window? Please read all three bullet points carefully.

Comment: sorry but I do not understand correctly. What is correct window to send `BM_SETIMAGE`? How to check if LoadImage succeed or not?

Comment: @DavidArutiunian: You send the button message to the button control you created one line above (`hButton`). SO is not the place to teach and learn. If you want to learn, go through the series of tutorials at [Learn to Program for Windows in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381399.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable the problem is I have no time to learn by tutorials now. I have a project in Win32api c++, and I try hard, but this problem really stops me very much. We learn from mistakes

Comment: I change to ```SendMessage((HWND)hButton,(UINT)BM_SETIMAGE,
(WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP,(LPARAM)hBmp);``` Is that right? I think not, because still doesnt work

Comment: @DavidArutiunian: In that case, consider reading [Teach Yourself Programming in Ten Years](http://norvig.com/21-days.html) as well. In short: You won't be able to write an application without knowing what you're doing. Why you signed up for a Win32 application contract with zero skill down is beyond me, and outrageously unprofessional. Regardless, this answer addresses the issues you are having, in very simple terms. If you are stumbling with this, you might as well give up.

Comment: @IInspectable I will not give up. Doing small steps, I understand how it works more and more.

Comment: @IInspectable I solved this problem. May be it is a bug, because on other machines it works, but I just moved whole code from `WM_CREATE` under `BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)`

Comment: @DavidArutiunian: If you don't know, why this (presumably) solved your problem, it didn't. It follows one of the ground rules of programming: If you don't know why your code works, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

to not overwrite @David Heffernan answer, here is a hint;

[image]

also, you don't need hinst for the button, just set it to NULL;

Comment: I solved this problem. I moved this code form `WM_CREATE` to  `BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)`